# google app engine: concurrent user registrations

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency

I know this is a classical problem, but I still don't know how to do it. On Google App Engine, I have a member registration form which uses jQuery's [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to check if a username exists. 
There of course is a concurrency problem: several users try to register, enter the same username, Validation finds the username available, and allow them to press "Add" at the approximately same time. Validation wouldn't detect this. In my application, username, email, and Personal ID should all be unique. How do I prevent the following code from having the concurrency problem:

```
member = Member()
member.username = self.request.get('username')
member.Pid = self.request.get('Pid')
member.email = self.request.get('email')
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the uniqueness constraint is on username, you have to use it as key in datastore and use transactions.

```
def txn():
    key = ndb.Key(Member, username)
    member = key.get()
    if member is not None:
        raise CustomAlreadyExistsException(member)  # This will abort txn
    member = Member(
        id=username,
        Pid=self.request.get('Pid'),
        email=self.request.get('email'),
        ...)
    member.put()
ndb.transaction(txn)
```

This makes sure only one person can register a username.

The jQuery helper would check if `ndb.Key(Member, userid).get()` gives a result or not. The GET is not transactional.

To improve usability client side in "reserving" a username after checking availability, you could use memcached as suggested by Daniel, but I'd call YAGNI, skip the complexity and rather let some people get validation error after submitting the form. Note that memcached is best effort and has no guarantees about anything.

If you need guaranteed uniqueness on multiple fields, you have to add Model classes for them and check in a cross group (XG) transaction.

```
class Pid(ndb.Model):
    member = ndb.KeyProperty()

class Email(ndb.Model):
    member = ndb.KeyProperty()

class Member(ndb.Model):
    pid = ndb.KeyProperty()
    email = ndb.KeyProperty()

    @property
    def pid_value(self):
        return self.pid.id()

    @property
    def email_value(self):
        return self.email.id()

def txn():
    member_key = ndb.Key(Member, username)
    pid_key = ndb.Key(PersonalId, self.request.get('Pid'))
    email_key = ndb.Key(Email, self.request.get('email'))

    member, pid, email = ndb.get_multi([member_key, pid_key, email_key])

    if member is not None or pid is not None or email is not None:
        raise CustomAlreadyExistsException(member, pid, email)  # This will abort txn

    # Create instances referencing each other
    email = Email(key=email_key, member=member_key)
    pid = Pid(key=pid_key, member=member_key)
    member = Member(
        key=member_key,
        pid=pid_key,
        email=email_key,
        ...)
    ndb.put_multi([member, pid, email])

ndb.transaction(txn, xg=True)
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement what you suggested. But there was an error message: BadRequestError: transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed with the High Replication datastore. I though that ndb is HRD? How do I solve this?

Comment: BTW, I checked my uploaded application in Google App Engine's Application settings. The item in "Datastore Replication Options:" does show "High Replication," so the error only occurs in the SDK environment?

Comment: dev_appserver.py --high_replication

Comment: Got it, many thanks. Another problem: I'd like to get username, pid, and email first. Can I define txn as "def txn(username, pid, email):" and then invoke the function by "ndb.transaction(txn(username, pid, email), xg=True)"? Because if I do so, I got an error message at the invocation: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: ndb.transaction(lambda: txn(username, pid, email), xg=True)

Comment: Done! Thanks a million, tesdal. You saved my life!

Comment: You're welcome! The ndb.transaction expects a callable (function) as argument, and will set up a transaction context before calling the callable. Lambda creates a callable that includes arguments. Leaving lambda out executes txn immediately outside transaction, then transaction tries to call the result of txn (None).

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use for memcache. Your Ajax validation function should put an entry into memcache to record that the username has been requested. It should also check both memcache and the datastore to ensure that the username is free. Similarly, the registration code should check memcache to ensure that the current user is the one who requested the username.

This nicely solves your concurrency problem, and the best thing is that entries in memcache expire by themselves, either on a timed basis or when the cache gets too full.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) When user A registers, the program will do "memcache.add('username', usernameA)", and when user B registers, wouldn't "memcache.add('username', usernameB)" overwrites usernameA? 2) How do I associate a username with some user, such that we know who wants what username? Thanks.

Comment: You should check memcache before adding. And you could try passing a (possibly random) unique ID along with both the Ajax call and the registration itself.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back soon enough. Daniel, would you elaborate more? Especially about my two questions. I still didn't have a clear concept.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with tesdal.
If you still want to implement the memcache tric sugested by Daniel, you should do something like "memcache.add(usernameA, dummy value, short period);". So you know that usernameA is reserved for a short period and wont conflict with "memcache.add(usernameB, ..."